proof of limit without L'Hospital's theorem
I am having trouble to prove these two statements, without L'Hospital's theorem.
This came from a series convergence test problem, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\ln n)^3}{n^3}$. If this is proven, then I can use the second statement and deduce $0 \le \frac{(\ln n)^3}{n^3} \le \frac{(\ln n)^3}{n}\frac{1}{n^2} \le \frac{1}{n^2}$, which converges.

For any $k \in \mathbb N,$ $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(\ln x)^k}{x}=0$
For some $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ and any $k \in \mathbb N$, $(\ln n)^k \le n $ for any $n \ge n_0$

For the first one, if L'Hospital is allowed, mathematical induction works. But without L'Hospital, I am kind of stuck.
Thanks for any help.

What have you thought/tried?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Thank you, I edited my question. I'll be more careful and put more information and details in future questions.

There are some flaws in your inequalities. I'd suggest using comparison test making profit of the fact that
$$\left(\dfrac{\ln x}{x}\right)^3<\dfrac{1}{x^a}$$
for some $a\in(1,1.89...)$ both functions do not intersect and the latter is larger and also $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{1}{n^a}<\infty$$.

Your statement #2 is not true as stated: there's no number $n_0$ making the inequality true for every $k$. Instead, "for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $(\ln n)^k \leq n$ for any $n \geq n_0$". In that phrasing $n_0$ can depend on $k$.

I'm quite confused on your 2nd statement, take for example : $$\ln(10)^3 > 12 > 10$$
As for the first statement, here's the most basic way I can think of, first show the following : $${\displaystyle \forall n\in \mathbb {N} \quad \lim _{x\to +\infty }{\frac {\mathrm {e} ^{x}}{x^{n}}}=+\infty }$$
The exponential, being a convex function, has its curve on top of its tangeant at zero, giving : ${\displaystyle \forall t\in \mathbb {R} \quad \mathrm {e} ^{t}\geq t+1} \\$
Let $x>0, n \in \mathbb N \\$
By using $t = \frac x {n+1}$ we get $\mathrm {e} ^{\frac x {n+1}}\geq \frac x {n+1}+1 > \frac x {n+1} \quad (*) \\$
However, $\mathrm {e} ^{\frac x {n+1}} = (\mathrm {e}^x)^{\frac 1 {n+1}} \\$
So we get using (*) : ${\displaystyle \mathrm {e} ^{x}>\left({\frac {x}{n+1}}\right)^{n+1}} = {\displaystyle \left({\frac {1}{n+1}}\right)^{n+1} \cdot x^{n+1}} = K \cdot x^{n+1}$, with $K = \frac {1}{n+1}$ being positive constant.
Finally getting : $ {\displaystyle \mathrm {e} ^{x}>K \cdot x^{n+1}}$ and by dividing by $x^n$ : $${\displaystyle  \frac {\mathrm e ^{x}}{x^n}>K \cdot x}$$
Which by comparison shows the limit goes to infinity.
Now let $y = \ln(x)$, $n \in \mathbb N$ and $n>k \\$ :
$$ 0 \leq \frac {( \ln(x))^k} x = \frac {y^k}{e^y} \leq (\frac {e^y}{y^n})^{-1}$$
And since $\frac {e^y}{y^n} \to +\infty$, we get $(\frac {e^y}{y^n})^{-1} \to 0$ and by squeeze theorem you get your limit.

Notice that $0<\frac{\ln x}{ x}<\frac{\ln ([x]+1)}{[x]}$, then instead of computing this limit, we can convert it into a limit in sequences. Let $x_n=\frac{\ln (x+1)}{x}$ and by using Stolz–Cesàro theorem, we get $\lim\limits_ {n\to\infty} x_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)}{n-(n-1)}=0$, then use squeeze theorem.
For $k=2$, only need to consider $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \ln^{2}(x+1)-\ln^{2}(x)$. [Use Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem]. Then prove your problem by induction.

$\log(x)$ is defined to be $\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt$. Obviously as $x \to \infty$ that means $x \geq1$ so we know that $\frac{1}{t}\leq1$. So we get
$$\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt\leq\int_1^x1dt=x-1\leq x \implies \log(x)\leq x ,\forall x\geq1$$
If we put $\sqrt{x}$ in the place of $x$ we get
$$\log(\sqrt{x})\leq\sqrt{x} \iff\log(x)\leq2\sqrt{x}\implies0\leq\frac{\log(x)}{x}\leq\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}
}$$
Therefore by the squeeze theorem  $$\lim_{x\to\infty}
\frac{\log(x)}{x}=0$$
Can you continue from here?

There are other definitions of $\ln$. But in any treatment in the context of calculus, your integral equation would soon be shown anyway.
